# How to change the text in a input from a Extension in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm creating an **extension** to **Firefox**. The idea is while I'm writing in an editable element like a TextArea inside of different pages, after selecting a part of the text, change it based on the option selected in a context menu. Similar to the Grammarly extension.

I'm able to select the different options, get the text, and apply the option that I want, but I am not able or I can not find the option to substitute the text with the new text.

This is an example of my code that is currently working:

```
browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, event, tab) => {
  const optionSeletect = info.menuItemId;         
  const option = optionSeleted(optionSeletect);   // Gets the option selected in the contextMenu.
  const arrayText = getSelectedTextAsArray(info); // Extract the text selected
  const newText = applyoption(arrayText,option);  // Return the new text desired as a string.
});
```

It would be great if someone could help me. Thanks a lot!